# What is an empty string in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm doing those challenges in FreeCodeCamp and I have to fill the "content:" property in one of the classes with "empty string".

What exactly empty string means? What should I put there?

Comment: `""` or `''` should do -- just a string with nothing in it :)

Answer (score 3):

As in other programming languages, an empty string is simply `''` (or `""`) without content.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the following in order to simulate an empty string in html5:

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use

- **content:"";**

("") indicates empty string.